# Axios baseURL is not appending with the URL in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I had made the axios setup with saga.js, when the user clicks the Register button have to dispatch an action and it will hit the request, everything is working fine, except appending the baseURL in the url, the url `http://users/register`,

My axios setup,

```
 import axios from 'axios';

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL : `https://test-url.com/`
});


export function postRequest(URL, payload) {
    return axiosClient.post(`/${URL}`, payload).then(response => response);
}
```

saga.js

```
import { put, takeEvery, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {register} from "./serviceWorker";
import { postRequest } from './helpers/axiosClient';
import actions from "./redux/actions";

function* registerUser(params) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(() => postRequest('/users/register', params.payload));
        console.log('response', response.data);
        yield put({
            type: actions.ON_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data,
        });
    } catch (error) {}
}

function* watchIncrementAsync() {
    yield takeEvery('ON_REGISTER', registerUser)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        watchIncrementAsync()
    ])
}
```

Comment: I had the problem when an instance method's relative path doesn't append to the base URL. The reason is that I used an incorrect config property name: `baseUrl` instead of `baseURL`.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I literally spent 1 hour thinking what's wrong in my code @MegaCasper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove the leading slash added to `URL` in `postRequest`, axios will use the base URL to build the full path.

```js
return axiosClient.post(URL, payload).then(response => response);
```

If you would like to understand what's happening, this is where axios [builds the full path](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/b7e954eba3911874575ed241ec2ec38ff8af21bb/lib/core/buildFullPath.js#L16-L19). It thinks you're [passing an absolute URL](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/b7e954eba3911874575ed241ec2ec38ff8af21bb/lib/helpers/isAbsoluteURL.js#L13) (since the path `'//users/register'` starts with a double slash) and doesn't use the base URL.